# Knockout.js and REST

Tags: javascript, rest, knockout.js

I'm testing the knockout.js MVVM framework. And I want to pull some data from a restful service. I have successfully connected to the service and it's getting the data but for some reason it's not binding to the page. I'm not sure if I'm doing something incorrectly after I use the ajax call to get the data. Here is the .js file:

```
function MessageCountDataModel() {

    var self = this;
    var allCounts = (function (){

    var json = null;

    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': "http://localhost:8080/API/getstats.json",
        'datatype': "json",
        'success': function(data){
            json = data;
        }            
    });
        return json;
   }) ();



}
    ko.applyBindings(new MessageCountDataModel());
```

And here is the bindings part of the HTML Page:

```
<body>
    <div data-bind="foreach: statlist">
        TypeCount: <strong data-bind="text: TypeCount"></strong>, Priority: <strong data-bind="text: SentDate"></strong>
        <br/>
</div>
    <script src="js/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="models/messagecount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: `foreach: statlist`, you have no observable statlist variable in your model.

Comment: Similarly, you have no observable variables `TypeCount` or `SentDate`. Any time you use `data-bind`, you must then provide the name of a Knockout observable to bind to.

Comment: Not to be picky, but nothing has to be observable.

Comment: I actually have that I think I forgot to copy it in:   self.statlist = ko.observablearray(allCounts[0]);

Comment: Are you seeing any error in the console?

Comment: allCounts is not observable so even if it changes, your statlist doesn't get updated. You don't actually need allCounts, update the statlist array on the ajax success method.

Comment: Can I know if self.statlist(data) is what you did?

Comment: self.allCounts = (function(){...})() and then you need to ensure your context in foreach is more like allCounts.statlist [or whatever the foo your dataset looks like]